# xpath matching elements whose attributes have no value

Tags: xpath, selenium-rc

I am looking at some HTML as follows

```
<tr>
  <td nowrap><a href=" ... " >some link</a></td>
  <td nowrap>col2</td>
  <td nowrap>col3</td>
</tr>
```

I plugged this into an xpath tester http://www.xpathtester.com/test and it refuses to run because the input is invalid.

Can I use xpath to select elements on the above input?
I am using selenium to click on the link contained in the row where the third `td` element has a specific value and figured xpath would be an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  The correct XPath is `//tr[td[3][.='col3']/td[1]/a`: the `<a>` contained within the first `<td>` contained within the `<tr>` that also contains `col3` in the third `<td>`.